# Setup file (created using Windows Service) is not working on Desktop location. I have created windows service using C# (In VS2010)

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2010, windows-services

I have created `Windows Service` using `C#` including (`.exe` file and `.msi` file in Debug folder)

ie. 1) `setup.exe` and `Tracking_Setup.msi`

Now, the problem is that when I try to run/Install setup.exe file from **D:\ (any other than C:\ ) Drive** it's working fine but when I try to copy this file on Desktop and then try to run/setup it's give me error  like

**Unable to locate application file 'Tracking_Setup.msi'.**

**See the setup log file located at 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD5AD0.tmp\install.log' for more information.**

I have give permission too this file and run as administrator too but still no luck.

Comment: You have to move both files to the same location...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy setup.exe on desktop also copy .msi file which will be there with setup.exe in debug directory and then try to install.